# Difference of pm-hibernate and systemctl hibernate

Tags: power-management, hibernate

I set up hibernation on my machine running 18.04. using `systemctl hibernate` mostly following this [guide](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/14/configuring-lubuntu-18-04-to-enable-hibernation-using-a-swap-file/?unapproved=11483&moderation-hash=d002dc3bd1438ff73a5e4144f1887c22#comment-11483). Working fine - just as using `pm-hibernate`

**What is the difference between those two?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather short answer to this would be that `systemd` is actively maintained, while `pm-utils` is not.

In fact, `pm-utils` has not been updated since 2010, so I would consider this software both ancient and obsolete.

It is advised to use `systemctl` from this point on.