# What is the difference between "systemctl hibernate" and "hibernate" commands?

Tags: power-management, hibernate, system, pm-utils

I configured hibernate function by the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-the-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04) for Ubuntu 20.04.

Then I tried `systemctl hibernate` and `hibernate` commands and both are working fine.

By description from `man`, `help` and because of different locations of `systemctl` and `hibernate` (from`whereis`, `which`) it seems that this commands have different implementation.

What is the difference between them? Which one should be used?

Related question: [Difference of pm-hibernate and systemctl hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153817/difference-of-pm-hibernate-and-systemctl-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hibernate` command was replaced by `systemctl hibernate`.
It is recommended to use `systemctl hibernate`.
`hibernate` command is still available in the system for compatibility reasons.

> In most Ubuntu and similar Linux distributions, the systemctl tool has
> replaced power management commands that were used in previous
> releases. The following commands for instance have been replaced by
> systemctl as shown below : halt → systemctl halt poweroff → systemctl
> poweroff reboot → systemctl reboot …. For compatibility reasons
> however, the old commands are still available in the system, but it is
> recommended to rely on systemctl.

Source: [How to shut down, restart, suspend and hibernate Linux](https://net2.com/how-to-shut-down-restart-suspend-and-hibernate-linux/)

How power management commands work:
[Shutdown, Reboot, Suspend and Hibernate a Linux System](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/shutdown-reboot-suspend-and-hibernate-a-linux-system.html)