# How to configure Hibernate button to not ask password for performing hibernate (for Simpler Off Menu extension for Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: sudo, power-management, password, hibernate, gnome-shell-extension

I configured hibernate as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-the-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04) and installed [`Simpler Off Menu` gnome-shell-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/) with the help of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379313/1548713) instruction.
`Hibernate` button is working but every time requires password to allow hibernate.
How to configure it to not ask password and perform hibernate right away like `suspend` button performs suspend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18,19,20 `system hibernate` command requires `sudo` for its execution:
["systemctl suspend" vs "systemctl hibernate" Permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189456/systemctl-suspend-vs-systemctl-hibernate-permission)

To disable password prompt `systemctl hibernate` command should be added to sudoers list (`/etc/sudoers.tmp`)
Use `sudo visudo` command and add to the end of the file the following line:

`<user_name> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate`

But now there is bug in `Simpler Off Menu` extension. Hibernate is performed in it by `systemctl hibernate`, not by `sudo systemctl hibernate` as required. This implementation is in file `SimplerOffMenu.kerkus@pm.me/extension.js`

I created corresponding issue for this extension:
[Bug in Ubuntu 20.04: Pressing [Hibernate] button asks to input password before performing hibernate](https://gitlab.com/K3rcus/simpler-off-menu/-/issues/7)

The last commit was made about 1 year ago. So the extension is not actively supported.

Below is the full details from the issue with workaround:

**Expected behavior**

Pressing `Hibernate` button executing `sudo systemctl hibernate`.
If there is appropriate user in sudoers list (`/etc/sudoers.tmp` edited by `sudo visudo`):

`<user_name> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate`

hibernate action is performed immediately after pressing `Hibernate` button.

**Actual result**

Pressing [Hibernate] button asks to input user password to perform authorization for the action.
In system log (`less /var/log/syslog`) there is an error - "Failed to hibernate system via logind: Access denied":

```
02:51:06 gnome-shell[1983]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x564b127af6f0 Gjs_ui_popupMenu_PopupSubMenuMenuItem.popup-menu-item popup-submenu-menu-item:last-child ("")] which is not in the stage.
02:51:06 Tgnome-shell[1983]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x564b127b6d00 StWidget:last-child] which is not in the stage.
02:51:06 gnome-shell[1983]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x564b12781480 StBoxLayout ("")] which is not in the stage.
02:51:13 systemd[1735]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
02:51:13 gnome-shell[5729]: Failed to hibernate system via logind: Access denied
02:51:27 gnome-shell[5729]: Failed to start hibernate.target: Access denied
02:51:27 gnome-shell[5729]: See system logs and 'systemctl status hibernate.target' for details.
```

After entering the password hibernate action probably is performed by not `systemctl hibernate` but some other command. I'm not sure but may be by `pm-hibernate` or `hibernate` commands - what is not recommended.

[Difference between "pm-hibernate" and "systemctl hibernate"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153817/difference-of-pm-hibernate-and-systemctl-hibernate)

> A rather short answer to this would be that systemd is actively maintained, while pm-utils is not.
> In fact, pm-utils has not been updated since 2010, so I would consider this software both ancient and obsolete.
> It is advised to use systemctl from this point on.

[Difference between "systemctl hibernate" and "hibernate":](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380102/what-is-the-difference-between-systemctl-hibernate-and-hibernate-commands)

> hibernate command was replaced by systemctl hibernate. It is recommended to use systemctl hibernate. hibernate command is still available in the system for compatibility reasons.

In Ubuntu 18,19,20 `system hibernate` command requires `sudo` for its execution:
["systemctl suspend" vs "systemctl hibernate" Permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189456/systemctl-suspend-vs-systemctl-hibernate-permission)

In implementation of `SimplerOffMenu` extension in `Hibernate` button the handler uses
`systemctl hibernate`, not `sudo systemctl hibernate` which is required to fix this issue.

**Fix**

Change `extension.js` file as follows:

```
function FuncHibernate(widget, event) {
    Main.overview.hide();       try {
       //fix start: added sudo
       //Util.trySpawnCommandLine('systemctl hibernate');
       Util.trySpawnCommandLine('sudo systemctl hibernate');
       //fix end
    } catch (err) {
        Main.notify("Error " + err);
    }
}
```

Fixed `extension.js` file is [here](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/GgCCUBJS5WSd5A).

**Workaround**

To fix this problem in Ubuntu 20.04 after the extension already installed it needs to do the following:

Change JS script of the extension which was installed here:

`/home/<your_user_name>/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/SimplerOffMenu.kerkus@pm.me/extension.js`

(you can find location of `extension.js` file by `sudo find /* -name "extension.js"`)

Then add `sudo` as described in the fix above and safe the file.

To apply the fix may be it will be enough just to save the file. I just in case performed the instruction from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379313/1548713):

- Disabled and enabled the extension,
  pressed config button on [the extension page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/)
- Pressed `Alt`+`F2`, entered `r` and pressed `Enter`
- Logged out and logged in